# XML To Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I want the function below to read an XML file and save all the data into the UserClassDict that is passed into the function. The UserClassDict saves the a  (username,User Class). The User Class has a property `List<int> ControlNumber` , where it stores the ControlNumbers.

The XML that it is trying to read looks like this :

```
<UserClassDictionary>
   <adolan>
      <ControlNumber>791301</ControlNumber>
   </adolan>
   <afeazell>
      <ControlNumber>790253</ControlNumber>
   </afeazell>
   <asnyder>
      <ControlNumber>790210</ControlNumber>
      <ControlNumber>790308</ControlNumber>
   </asnyder>
   <semery/>
   <showard/>
   <talexander/>
</UserClassDictionary>
```

The problem that I'm having is that the LINQ in the function doesn't seem distinguish between the different xml nodes. It doesn't seem to set the  node to the Key and the  node to the Value.

```
 static void XMLToDictionary(Dictionary<string,User> UserClassDict)
        {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("UserClassDictionary.xml");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        doc.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString();

        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(str);

            foreach (XElement element in document.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements == false))
        {
            int keyInt = 0;
            string keyName = element.Name.LocalName;

            while (UserClassDict.ContainsKey(keyName))
                keyName = element.Name.LocalName + "_" + keyInt++;

            UserClassDict.Add(keyName, element.Value);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Your xml do not have root node

Comment: oh it does, I just took it out. The root node is <UserClassDictionary>

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of `user` element to store users in xml. E.g. `<user name="adolan"><controlNumbers><number>123</number><number>546</number></controlNumbers></user>`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky That actually makes a lot of sense. I'm not too good at linq, so i'll try reshape what I have to display this sort of XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a `StreamWriter` or `XmlTextWriter`. You can just use [`XElement.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435.aspx) instead.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("UserClassDictionary.xml");
Dictionary<string, List<string>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach(XElement subNode in root.Elements().Where(x => x.Elements().Count() > 0))
{
    values.Add(subNode.Name.LocalName, subNode.Elements("ControlNumber")
        .Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
}
```

Your other reason was you were using `Descendents` instead of [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) in your loop. This looked for EVERY sub node in your xml, even gradchild nodes.

Comment: the foreach loop isn't working. ERROR: "Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'methold group'?"

Comment: @MaylorTaylor See my edit, I forgot to write `Elements` as a method.

Comment: I just noticed that some of my nodes are blank...which causes an error. Any way around this?

Comment: @MaylorTaylor, which nodes? Are they under your root?

Comment: It seems that some of the <username> nodes are empty. This is b/c the program isn't pulling any ControlNumbers for that user for one reason or another (which is normal). But of course I don't need these blank nodes to be added to the dictionary.

Comment: @MaylorTaylor, could you edit your post to give an example of what you mean? I edited again with a possibility.

Comment: Ok, I added 3 blank nodes as they appear in my XML document. I noticed they don't have a closing node..so that could be a problem??? BUt in your edit, the x.Elements().Count has this error "Operator > cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'"

Comment: @MaylorTaylor, fixed. Try again. And if you ever see that type of error, it's because what you (I) typed in is really a method, not a property. Just add `()` and that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your xml and create dictionary of users with Linq to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("UserClassDictionary.xml");
Dictionary<string, User> users = 
     xdoc.Root.Elements()
         .Select(u => new User {
             Name = u.Name.LocalName,
             ControlNumber = u.Elements().Select(cn => (int)cn).ToList()
          })
         .Where(u => ControlNumber.Any())
         .ToDictionary(u => u.Name);
```

Or if you wish to update existing dictionary

```
var users = from u in xdoc.Root.Elements()
            where u.Elements().Any()
            select new User {
                 Name = u.Name.LocalName,
                 ControlNumber = u.Elements().Select(cn => (int)cn).ToList()
             };

foreach(var user in users)
     UserClassDict.Add(user.Name, user);
```

Comment: The second one works like I want it to. But when I try to see the information and use '?UserClassDict.Keys' I get a list of the usernames. That's fine. But then when I use '?UserClassDict.Values' and I get just a generic "{ProgramName.User}"

Comment: @MaylorTaylor and what is your expected result? All users will be in dictionary. How exactly you are looking and dictionary content? In debugger? I just verified code above. It creates dictionary with 6 users, first three have control numbers inside.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I believe the OP does not want to record users that do not have control numbers.

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't see such requirement, but I'll add filter if OP needs it

Comment: @gunr2171 that's correct. If they dont' have controlNumbers assigned to them, then I don't need them in the Dictionary.

Comment: @MaylorTaylor OK, updated. BTW I suggest you to rename `ControlNumber` property to `ControlNumbers` thus it is a collection of numbers